# Header file not found Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, header

I have managed to successfully download and build this project on its own, source can be found here: https://github.com/FuruyamaTakeshi/DLNA/tree/master

It builds fine and runs on simulator and device.

When I go to add all of the .h and .m files to my own project as they are in the folder, Xcode complains about over 100 header files not found when i try to build.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Check your frameworks - it's likely the project you're pulling the files from are using frameworks you haven't added to your project yet. This can be done by clicking the .xcodeproj file at the top left of the Project navigator. Frameworks are added at the bottom of the General tab of your app target.

Comment: How did you add the files to your project? Did you drag and drop? If so, did you check the option to copy resources if needed? You have to be sure these files are in your project's directory to run and not being referred to outside the app.